# Падение производительности приложения при переопределения дизайна окна на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, производительность

Делаю приложение, подобие графического редактора, переопределил стиль окна по примеру из [статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/158561/) на хабре. Решил саму рабочую область сделать на InkCanvas, но при запуске приложения очень сильно чувствуется что процесс отрисовки в канвасе тормозит. При отключении стиля окна, тормоза пропадают. С чем это может быть связанно, как это решить? Может есть другой способ переопределить стиль окна??

Comment: Стиль который у вас получился покажите

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, залил https://yadi.sk/d/vqxji3vf3DtHc9